# How to show multiple images in a RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to develop a gallery app in android studio and I'm using a RecyclerView Layout to load efficiently the images on the screen but whenever I scroll down, after a few images the app crush. The error I get is **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError** so I thought that I was making a mistake with the class adapter but I couldn't find any error (I follow the steps given in the android documentation [Create a List with RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) ). I tried to show a thumbnail of each image instead of the actual image but after scrolling down a few images the app crush and I get the **The application may be doing too much work on its main thread** error

I'll leave the code of the adapter class. If you need more code example or more info tell me please!

Pd: Sorry I'm not clear, my English is pretty bad and I don't have experience asking questions here plus I this is my first app in android.

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView image;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.IMAGEN);
    }
}

private ArrayList<File> images = new ArrayList<>();
private Activity activity;

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<File> images, Activity activity){
    this.images = images;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View v = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_item, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(images.get(position).getAbsolutePath());
    //holder.image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    Picasso.get().load(images.get(position)).resize(300,300).centerCrop().into(holder.image);
}

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(null);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return images.size();
}
```

}

Comment: use picasso or glide to load images in recycler view

Comment: I found a tutorial of Picasso, it shows how to make a gallery app with Picasso an recyclerView, I'm going to see whether it helps me to find the solution to my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I used Picasso but even resizing the picture to 10x10 px... Picasso.get().load(images.get(position)).resize(10,10).centerCrop().into(holder.image); 
wasn't enough. I used the ic_louncher_icon image and it does't run out of memory, I don't know what I am doing wrong...

Comment: please update your code here so i can check it and find the issue

Comment: Check it, I already update it, but it is almost the same...

Comment: check my answer and let me know if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use Glide.
If you don`t want, you can clean your image in onViewRecycled
Something like

```
override fun onViewRecycled(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder)
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(null)
}
```

Comment: I tried overriding the onViewRecycled method but it didn't work, I got the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError again... I'll do some reasearch of Glide

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Glide library to upload images more efficiently in recycler view. Also, try to compress the bitmap first and then set in the image view.
By compressing image, OutOfMemory Exception will get resolved

TAKEN FROM Someone's StackOverflow Answers. Do not remember link now

```
`public  Bitmap compressInputImage(Uri inputImageData)
{


    try
    {
        bitmapInputImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), inputImageData);
        if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() > 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() > 2048)
        {
            dpBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, 1024, 1280, true);

        }
        else if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() > 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() < 2048)
        {
            dpBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, 1920, 1200, true);

        }
        else if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() < 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() > 2048)
        {
            dpBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, 1024, 1280, true);

        }
        else if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() < 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() < 2048)
        {
            dpBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, bitmapInputImage.getWidth(), bitmapInputImage.getHeight(), true);

        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        dpBitmap = bitmapInputImage;

    }
    return dpBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this code

```
Picasso.get().load(images.get(position)).resize(300,300).centerCrop().into(holder.image);
```

to

```
 Picasso.get().load(Uri.fromFile(new File(images.get(position).getDataPath()))).resize(300,300).centerCrop().into(holder.image);
```

This will create actual URI of the image from external storage

> **Solution 2**

append this with your image

```
file://
```

Example

```
Picasso.get().load("file://"+images.get(position)).resize(300,300).centerCrop().into(holder.image);
```

Comment: I fixed it!!! I changed the layout of the activity_main.xml from ConstraintLayout to RelativeLayout and it worked! I don't know why though, so I have to do some research of the layouts now.
Thanks for all the effor you make to help me!